# Yodlee MFA - Container Info Indicates There is MFA

Tags: yodlee

In my scripting logic, after I `addItemForContentService`, I check to see if the content service requires MFA by calling `getContentServiceInfo` and checking if the returned object has an `mfaType` property. If it does, I kick off a chain of tasks, where I `startRefresh7` and put it in MFA refresh mode. Then I `getRefreshInfo1`, and check if its in MFA mode, then do `getMFAResponse`. However, for a particular institution I get this as a response:

```
{ 
  isMessageAvailable: true,
  fieldInfo: { 
     questionAndAnswerValues: [],
     numOfMandatoryQuestions: -1,
     mfaFieldInfoType: 'SECURITY_QUESTION' 
  },
   timeOutTime: 100030,
   itemId: 10178678,
   errorCode: 0,
   retry: false 
}
```

Does this mean that there really is no MFA (I view -1 as a falsey value) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Since getMFAResponse returned errorCode = 0 that means there is no more MFA required and Yodlee was able to connect to the bank site successfully. This means, you can proceed with next steps.

Also, if you are doing integration for the first time with Yodlee. It is recommended to use Site Based approach or you can have a look at new RESTful Yodlee APIs released recently.

The approach you have mentioned above is not recommended anymore.